# 'HttpRequest' does not contain a definition for 'Files'

Tags: c#, file-upload, http-post, httprequest

I have one post method in which one file upload control is there. To get that uploaded file in controller, I am getting error like below :

```
Error   CS1061  'HttpRequest' does not contain a definition for 'Files' and no extension method 'Files' accepting a first argument of type 'HttpRequest' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

My code is like below :

```
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> TeamUserDetail(TeamUsers model)
        {
            var file = Request.Files[0];
            return View();
        }
```

At Request.Files[0] it is giving error shown above. MVC6 is used in project.

Please guide me for it. Am I missing any reference to add?

Thank You

Comment: http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/288/asp-net-5-uploading-files-with-asp-net-mvc-6

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MVC 6 used another mechanism to upload files. You can get more examples on [GitHub](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/commit/437eb93bdec0d9238d672711ebd7bd3097b6537d) or [other sources](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/288/asp-net-5-uploading-files-with-asp-net-mvc-6). Just use `IFormFile` as a parameter of your action:

```
public FileDetails UploadSingle(IFormFile file)
{
    FileDetails fileDetails;
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(file.OpenReadStream()))
    {
        var fileContent = reader.ReadToEnd();
        var parsedContentDisposition = ContentDispositionHeaderValue.Parse(file.ContentDisposition);
        fileDetails = new FileDetails
        {
            Filename = parsedContentDisposition.FileName,
            Content = fileContent
        };
    }

    return fileDetails;
}

[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> UploadMultiple(ICollection<IFormFile> files)
{
    var uploads = Path.Combine(_environment.WebRootPath,"uploads"); 
    foreach(var file in files)
    {
        if(file.Length > 0)
        {
            var fileName = ContentDispositionHeaderValue.Parse(file.ContentDisposition).FileName.Trim('"');
            await file.SaveAsAsync(Path.Combine(uploads,fileName));
        }
    }
    return View();
}
```

You can see current contract of `IFormFile` in [asp.net sources](https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/blob/dfe2d414376972a84b97acdca4ade84341bd24d4/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Http.Abstractions/IFormFile.cs).

Comment: This is probably almost outdated, but the return should be outside the foreach-loop

Comment: @codeshinobi fixed ^_^